# check whether the second line is empty

Tags: bash

I have a .csv file that contains 3 columns like this:

```
Name,Last,Value
pablo,car,20
```

Is there any way to check whether the second line of this .csv file is empty? Something like this:

```
if second-line-empty; then
   echo "empty"
else
   echo "not empty"
fi
```

In this case, all three fields in the 2nd line should be empty and my file should only contain this line:

```
Name,Last,Value
```

Comment: So you want exactly one line with `Name,Last,Value`?  You talk about the second line being empty, what if it's empty and there's a third (or more) lines that are not empty?  Do you know for sure that there will always be at least one line, and that it will contain the header fields?

Comment: Would it be enough to detect a _single_ line?

Comment: @AndyDalton Yes in my intended script, if the second line is empty, it means all the following lines are empty as well, So I just want to know if the 2nd line is empty

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, if my .csv file contains only the first line, I want to be informed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if [ "$(wc -l <file.csv)" -eq 1 ]; then
    echo file only contains a single line
fi
```

This runs `wc -l` on the file's contents.  If this results in a count of 1 line, then the file only contains a single line.

Note that an "empty line" contains a newline character (but nothing else). The code above will detect whether the file does not contain a second line *at all*, as in the example that you show at the end of the question.